# How can I use the github pages domain name and point it to serve the site hosted in netlify?

Tags: github, github-pages, netlify

I currently have `username.netlify.com` as my website. The content is stored in a private gitlab repository and served/deployed via netlify.

I additionally have registered `username.rbind.io` for myself which was free. But apparently this is being blocked by some corporate firewalls.

What I would like is to use `username.github.io` and serve the site from netlify, but keep my files in gitlab private.

In netlify, I added a custom domain `username.github.io` and the **Check DNS configuration** warning shows up which says

```
DNS configuration
Point username CNAME record to username.netlify.com

Log in to the account you have with your DNS provider, and add a CNAME record for username pointing to username.netlify.com.

username CNAME username.netlify.com.

If you’ve already done this, allow up to 24 hours for the changes to propagate, or check our documentation for more information.
```

I have added a `CNAME` file to the root of my `username.github.io` repository with `username CNAME username.netlify.com` in it.

But now I got an email saying

```
The page build completed successfully, but returned the following warning for the `master` branch:

The CNAME `usernamecname username.netlify.com.` is not properly formatted. See https://help.github.com/articles/troubleshooting-custom-domains/#github-repository-setup-errors for more information.
```

Ultimately, I want to enter `username.github.io` and I should get my static site served by netlify.

---

I tried out redirects with `netlify.toml`. Thus it redirects to my `rbind.io` domain, but this is not what I want. I want to see `username.github.io` in my browser address bar to see my site.

`netlify.toml`

```
[[redirects]]
  from = "https://username.netlify.com/*"
  to = "https://username.rbind.io/:splat"
  status = 301
  force = true
```